# What functions do EMC filters in variable frequency drives serve?

Tags: filter, emc, vfd, emi-filtering

Most VFDs I've seen have EMC filters in them, though in many cases they're optional or can be disabled by the user. Exactly what function do these filters perform? What problem are they intended to solve or prevent? And under what circumstances would one enable or disable such a filter?

Comment: My guesses for problems solved include preventing common-mode voltages between the AC and DC bus (caused external to the VFD) from damaging the drive rectifier, and preventing switching noise from the inverter stage from coupling back onto the AC line. I could imagine not wanting such a filter in cases where the AC feed is corner-grounded, in which case the typical filter design could be overvoltaged. But I'm just looking at the designs and trying to guess; I'd like someone to tell me what's actually going on here.

Answer (score 2):

> "though in many cases they're optional or can be disabled by the user"

ABB has a [sheet here](https://library.e.abb.com/public/ca86a30f9f47dff9c1257a39002da2f7/en_ACS880_01_EMC_filter_disconn_inst_A.pdf) giving reason to NOT use filter.

[image]

Good catch by ABB on the safety.